# self.assertRaises as a context manager with msg argument not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

Please check the below code:

```
import unittest


CORRECT_MESSAGE = 'Correct message'
WRONG_MESSAGE = 'Wrong message'


def fn():
    raise KeyError(CORRECT_MESSAGE)


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        # I am expecting this test to fail as the msg I am
        # checking is WRONG_MESSAGE, and not CORRECT_MESSAGE.
        with self.assertRaises(KeyError, msg=WRONG_MESSAGE):
            fn()


unittest.main()
```

---

As mentioned in the comment, I am expecting this test to fail, because the message I am checking (`WRONG_MESSAGE`) is incorrect, but the test passes.

**What am I missing? I have checked: [assertRaises(exception, *, msg=None)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises).**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will answer my own question.

---

I misunderstood the usage of `msg`. From [Python's official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.debug):

> All the assert methods accept a msg argument that, if specified, is used as the error message on failure.

**It is for debugging purposes.**

e.g.

```
import unittest


CORRECT_MESSAGE = 'Correct message'
WRONG_MESSAGE = 'Wrong message'


def fn():
    return
    # Don't raise an exception.
    # raise KeyError(CORRECT_MESSAGE)


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        with self.assertRaises(KeyError, msg=WRONG_MESSAGE):
            fn()


unittest.main()
```

In the output we will get:

> AssertionError: KeyError not raised : Wrong message

`msg` is used when the assertion error is not raised.

---

The actual solution is to use [assertRaisesRegex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaisesRegex) if we want to do check the exception message.

e.g.

```
import unittest


CORRECT_MESSAGE = 'Correct message'
WRONG_MESSAGE = 'Wrong message'


def fn():
    raise KeyError(CORRECT_MESSAGE)


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_will_pass(self):
        # This will check if the error message is CORRECT_MESSAGE.
        with self.assertRaisesRegex(KeyError, CORRECT_MESSAGE):
            fn()

    def test_will_fail(self):
        # This will check if the error message is WRONG_MESSAGE.
        with self.assertRaisesRegex(KeyError, WRONG_MESSAGE):
            fn()

unittest.main()
```