# Getting Python assertRaises to check for message

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest, assert

I want to use assertRaises and check for the error message too. According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) I have to use it as a context manager.

```
with self.assertRaises(ValueError, msg='Invalid id format.'):
    api.get_by_id('a')
```

This results in the following error:

```
TypeError: assertRaises() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callableObj'
```

I get the exact same error if I use it without `msg`.

Using it like `assertRaises(exception, callable, *args, **kwds)` works fine, but that obviously can't process the error message.

I don't understand why Python can't recognise the use case I'm going for.

Python 3.7.10, MacOS Monterey 12.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things - first of all, it's hard to tell what actually happens but there must be some other error in your code because
`with self.assertRaises(ValueError, msg='Invalid id format.'):` should work perfectly fine (tested on Python 3.10)

2nd thing - msg argument does not do what you want it to do - [self.assertRaises as a context manager with msg argument not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58687475/self-assertraises-as-a-context-manager-with-msg-argument-not-working-as-expected)

Link provided also explains how to check for error message with  [assertRaisesRegex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaisesRegex)